# Clip Raster Data of risk area with boundary polygone of forest using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, raster-calculator

I'm new to the GIS world.

I need to find the areas that are at moderate (land cover = 1) and high risk (land cover = 2) of illegal logging in a forest. I already calculate the areas of high and moderate risk from the land cover raster using the raster calculator, but I have to make sure that land is within the forest boundaries, which is a shapefile.

What do I do next?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you just need to clip your risk raster with the forest shapefile.  To do this use Clip Raster tool: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm